# Is it Possible ? To check student information by Roll no: using simple webpage in html + javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html javascript expert,

**1:** is this possible to make a simple webpage in **html** also using **javascript** to store student information.

**2:** The webpage should show a search box to check then individual result of a particular student by **Roll No**.

[image]

upon enter the **Roll No**. it should display the data of that student.

for example:

```
First Name: john:
Marks obtained: 567:
Institute: MCdonal
Percentage: 90%
```

thanks

fiddle example will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Most things are possible with software. What is most often not possible: to put up a question that only lists requirements; but that doesn't show any efforts of solving the problem yourself. This reads as if you would expect us to do your (home)work.

Comment: Unless everyone's going to come and use the **same** browser on the **same** computer, you're going to need a backend to store this information in and query it from.

Comment: @GhostCat i want a simple webpage using html and javascript. i will add student data in html. The only thing i want to fetch that student information by roll no: i think this is possible. thanks.

Comment: And what prevents you to start working on that? I understand that you *want* us to do that work. And as said: will not work out this way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i just need a simple webpage to show a search box. when someone put the Roll No: and enter that..his/her information will be displayed. i will add every individual student data in html. So, i think this is so much easy...if you can please do it. thanks

Comment: You're asking other people to do your homework, this is not OK.

Comment: let us know how you add student data in html, then only we can help

Comment: @GhostCat i am stuck in step..how to fetch that information of a particular student. i dont know how to do that. thanks

Comment: @ShubhamKundu ok lets show that...and if possible just tell me that..how to fetch particular student info by Roll number.

Comment: And we dont know what you expect from us. You got a whole bunch of feedback by now. Step back. Digest. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... and most importantly: better delete this question now; and come back later and write up a **better** one. And read [mcve] for example. Again: this is not a **we write code for you** service. Especially when things are simple, then **you** search for tutorials. Not us.

Comment: I know. That often happens when newbies show up here; just *expecting* that this site exists to solve their problems. Ignoring that this site has its rules and policies. In that sense: you are not dis-appointed. You got dis-illusioned. Because your *assumptions* how this site works ... simply dont match up with the people that **make up** this community. And sorry: you problem, not mine. It is not my responsibility to uphold *your* misconceptions about this community.

Comment: Sigh. Sure, if you think it is *smart* to pick up a fight only you are fighting; fine with us. Input matching the criteria of this site is *always* welcome. Your question does not meet this criteria, this is all we are telling you. And if you want to have fun: print out your comments; put them in a cupboard, and read them in 3, 5 years, when you are more grown up person. I am pretty sure you will have a good lough then. Over and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this:

```js
var studentArray = [{rollno:'rollno1', fname:'fname1', marks:'marks1', institute:'institute1', percentage: 'percentage1'},{rollno:'rollno2', fname:'fname2', marks:'marks2', institute:'institute2', percentage: 'percentage2'}];

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var roll = document.getElementById("roll").value;
    var student, info;
    for (i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
        student = studentArray[i];
        if (student.rollno == roll) {
            info = "First Name: " + student.fname + "<br />";
            info += "Marks Obtained: " + student.marks + "<br />";
            info += "Institute: " + student.institute+ "<br />";
            info += "Percentage: " + student.percentage + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("stuInfo").innerHTML = info;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="roll" />
<button id="search">Search</button>
<p id="stuInfo"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for your kindly code...hover i test it in jsfiddle..where that is not working..could you kindly give me that in jsfiddle. thanks bundles

Comment: Edited the answer, check now

Comment: @Shabham thanks bundles bundles..i want the same as you did for me.

Comment: Welcome, you can upvote my answer and click the 'tick' mark (at the left top of my answer) if you think this is the correct answer